# `tcl/auto.tcl could not be extracted! fopen: Not a directory` error with pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

When I try to use pyinstaller on my .py file, which is a tkinter aplication, the returned .exe file gives me this error and closes:

```
tcl/auto.tcl could not be extracted!
fopen: Not a directory
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Comment: I am on mac by the way, it may have something to be with it